# validate checkbox input must be checked one only by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, validation, checkbox

i have form with checkbox and submit method by jquery like this :

```js
$("form.adj_baru").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (confirm('Anda yakin akan submit ?')) {
                    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
                    var cekbox = $("input[name=size]").val();
                    if (cekbox === "") {
                        alert("Pilih salah satu ukuran !");
                        return;
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'adj/adj_crud.php', //type='add_adj'
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        async: false,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class='adj_baru'>
  <label>Checkbox : </label><br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='size' value='m'>M<br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='size' value='l'>L<br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='size' value='xl'>XL<br>
  <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT'>
  </form>
  </body>
```

the alert `alert("Pilih salah satu ukuran !")` not working when the checkbox empty. how to alert if the checkbox not checked **either** and checked **no more than one**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just count the checked checkboxes with .length. See snippet. Then you can decide, what to do if a certain amount of checkboxes were checked (or if none is checked).

```js
$("form.adj_baru").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var checked = $("input[name=size]:checked").length;
                if (checked === 1) {
                  alert("1 checked");
                } else if (checked > 1) {
                  alert("More than 1 checked");
                } else {
                  alert("None checked");
                }
                return false;
            });
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class='adj_baru'>
  <label>Checkbox : </label><br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='size' value='m'>M<br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='size' value='l'>L<br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='size' value='xl'>XL<br>
  <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT'>
  </form>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you update the part below. Check if there are checkboxes that are checked.

```
                var cekbox = $("input[name=size]:checked").length;
                if (cekbox == 0) {
                    alert("Pilih salah satu ukuran !");
                    return;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to check if the checkbox i checked:

```
                var cekbox = $("input:checked").length;
                if (cekbox == 0) {
                    alert("Pilih salah satu ukuran !");
                    return;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 if ($("input:checked[name=size]").length != 1) {
      alert("Pilih salah satu ukuran !");
      return;
 }
```

Here is the demo https://jsfiddle.net/8wzcyoe5/